# Are uncountable nouns considered irregular plurals like man men?

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, irregular

Is "rice", for example, considered an irregular plural?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the more common usage (as an [uncountable, or mass noun](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=uncountable+noun&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=nY9RT7XkN6ex0AWzsKjsCw&ved=0CCAQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3b6b42e17dd83c7b&biw=1264&bih=902)), "rice" isn't a plural, so the issue of whether it's regular or not simply doesn't arise. But when we speak of, say, different [rices of the world](http://www.earthprint.com/productfocus.php?id=FAO102720), it's just a regular plural.

On the other hand, it's not impossible for a word which is a mass noun to have an irregular plural. In some contexts *fish* is a mass noun *(Japan consumes much of the world's fish)*. And in some other contexts, it's a countable noun that's irregular in that the plural is the same as the singular *(I caught three fish)*. But it can also be a regular plural *(The parable of the loaves and the fishes)*.

Comment: +1 for good examples. What is the notion of countability doing here? EG. we say a real number, or the real numbers, even though they are uncountable, and same for an integer or the integers, which we call countably infinite.

Comment: @karthik: The notion of "countability" is here because OP asked whether *uncountable nouns* could be considered "irregular plurals". To which I'm saying *"No, because in its 'pure' form a mass/uncountable noun doesn't have the singular/plural attribute anyway"*. But in fact many if not most such nouns do have 'countable' variants -  which, like most other nouns, have regular plurals. *Fish* is an oddity in that respect, but you could call *man* a mass noun in some contexts (**Man is just a small component of the thin 'bio-film' covering this planet**) - unquestionably with an irregular plural.

Comment: +1: It is worth mentioning that certain mass nouns (rice, toast, cattle, corn, etc.) are count nouns that require a *counter* to refer to individual elements in the mass: one doesn't say "three toasts" unless one is talking about a salute involving alcoholic beverages; one says "three slices of toast" instead.

Comment: @Karthik, the discussion is about a linguist's notion of countability: your question seems to assume that it is the mathematician's concept of countability, which is quite different and not relevant here.

Comment: @ColinFine  yes, I got it after FumbleFinger's response. I took the uncountability to math. :)

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not the case that *rice* has a singular form *rice* and an identical plural form. One way to tell is by considering subject-verb agreement. If there were a plural *rice,* then we would expect to see examples where the verb is plural, such as **rice are white.* Not only do we not see such examples, but we find them to be ungrammatical. This same test can be applied to other nouns to discover if they simply have a plural form that shares its shape with the singular form (e.g., *sheep are stupid*) or not (e.g., **water are wet*).

(the * indicates an ungrammatical string)